# Migrate with truffle deployer by using new

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, truffle-deployment

Hi I am trying to figure out what is the right way to migrate the contract by using new() method of the contract. The following does not work, the contract does not seam to be migrated (though it is deployed). What am I missing here?

```
var UidProvider = artifacts.require("./UidProvider.sol");

module.exports = async function(deployer) {

  await deployer.then(async function() {
   return UidProvider.new();
  });


  return;

}
```

Comment: Copy the default migration file and change in it the name of the contract from Migration to UidProvider :/

Comment: Why do you want to use new?